# How can I connect a single USB device to my LXC container?

Tags: usb, lxc, lxd

## TL;DR

- I have two software radio devices attached to my Linux server.
- I have an LXC container running on the Linux server.
- Both software radios have the same productid and vendorid.
- How do I attach only one of the software radios to the LXC container?

#### Why?

Because I want to!

More serious answer: I give less-trusted users access to LXC container, and not to the LXD host. I want these users to only see one of the software radios.

## Debugging

#### Sanity check

- I am running a third-party utility which flashes the radios via USB
- I first connect/allow USB to both radios

  - command: `lxc config device add my-container usrpUSB usb productid=6010 vendorid=0403`
- I run the flashing utility, and it works
- I disconnect USB

  - command: `lxc config device remove my-container usrpUSB`
- I run the flashing utility, and it fails
- Conclusion: lxc USB connector works as expected

#### Finding what changed

- Idea: if I can find what files that `lxc config` changed on the container, maybe I can do it manually, so:
- Connect USB (see command above)
- List container files

  - `find / -ls > /tmp/find_with_usb.txt`
- Disconnect USB (see command above)
- List container files

  - `find / -ls > /tmp/find_without_usb.txt`
- Compare the two

  - There are over a hundred new files
  - None of them are `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices
  - The files are mostly in `/var/lib/lxcfs` and `/sys/fs/cgroup` directories
  - I am not sure what the source is for these on the LXD system
- Conclusion: manual path/character-device mapping will not work.

## So?

- Is there some other way to do this?
- I don't see any options for further constraining USB devices ([source](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/reference/devices_usb/))

Comment: It's not looking promising. I see in source code https://github.com/canonical/lxd/blob/main/lxd/device/usb.go#L23 `usbIsOurDevice`, which is coded only to look at `vendorid` and `productid`

Answer (score 0):

Since lxc autodev isn't automatically configuring the device you want, you're left having to configure the node.
Try using a control group to differentiate between the devices and/or using a hook to create the device node prior to the container's start (although, check for TOCTTOU via a misconfiguration).
Or hook scripts to handle the node device creation at an opportune time, be it 'pre-mount' of its filesystem, or 'pre-start' to run scripts in the host's namespace prior to the container's start.

Ref: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html
• /DEV DIRECTORY
• CONTROL GROUPS ("CGROUPS")